# nativescript-camera version 3.3.0 not compatible in framework android 2.5.0

Tags: android, nativescript

I am building an application in nativescript. To access camera I am using plugin nativescript-camera.

But when I installed plugin, I got an error message:
 "nativescript-camera 3.0.0 for android is not compatible with the currently installed framework version 2.5.0."

Does anybody knows, what's going wrong? I've tried to update the plugin nativescript-camera, but got same result.

there is my code:
main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text="Take a picture yo" class="title" />
        <Image id="myImage" />
        <Button text="Take" tap="onTake" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page.js

```
var application = require("application");
var cameraModule = require("nativescript-camera");
var myImage;
exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    myImage = page.getViewById("myImage");
    myImage.src = "https://placehold.it/150x150";
    page.bindingContext = {};
}
exports.onTake=function(args){
    if(application.android)
    {
        var permissions = require('nativescript-permissions');
        permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, "I need these permissions because I'm cool")
          .then(function() {
             console.log("Permission OK");
              cameraModule.takePicture({
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        keepAspectRatio: true,

    }).then(function (imageSource) {
        myImage.src="";
        myImage.src = imageSource;
    });
          })
          .catch(function() {
             console.log("Permission Failed");
          });    
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried downdating the plugin?

Comment: yes, I tried to nativescript-camera version 0.0.8, there no error message, but when I clicked button to access camera nothing respon

Comment: then it sounds like you are doing something wrong, i have a copy of the app im developing and the copy is written in ns2, it uses 0.0.8 for the camera and it works fine

Comment: really? I don't know whats wrong with my code

Comment: well i cant help as i cant see it

Comment: can you post your code?please

Comment: if you can add the code you use to your question, you might get more help

Comment: I've update my question

Comment: fix, I get the solve :) it's must to change with nativescript-camera version 0.0.8. thank you very much @mast3rd3mon :)